# EditText not accepting an input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 2 `EditText`s on my screen. The first one works fine, but the second doesn't. I click on the first `EditText` and can enter text. But click on the second `EditText` and any input continues to appear in the first `EditText`.

Looking at other questions on the subject, there is talk of using `setFocus` and having `onClick` listeners for the `EditText` fields. Is this correct?

I have another app which had several screens with multiple `EditText`s and never had to do this.

This is my current XML:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/namLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/name" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/namTxt"
    android:layout_below="@id/namLabel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="200sp" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/numLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/namTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingTop="20sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:text="@string/units" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/numTxt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/numLabel"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/numLabel"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:minWidth="50sp"  />
```

This is all the relevant code I have in the `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);

    namText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namTxt);
    numText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numTxt);
```

Please don't tell me I have to add a whole load of `onClickListeners` for these fields?

Comment: Are you assigning any listener to your edittext?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` from the numTxt?

Comment: can you post your whole xml file?

Comment: Found answer - will tick it later...(have to wait 2 days to answer my own question).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I just had to add the `setFocusableInTouchMode` to both EditText's:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I didn't do that in my last app, so no idea why I have to now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any listeners or setFocus. The only "strange" thing I see is that you are not wrapping your xml in a RelativeLayout. It should work just fine, just tested it.